# Groovy Removing characters from beginning of string

Tags: groovy

Please help me in solving a problem which i am facing. I few string which are not of fixed length. e.g

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx111
xxxxxxxxxxxx111
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx1111
xxxxxxxxxxx223
```

all i want is to convert them to.

```
xxx111
xxx111
xxx1111
xxx223
```

I have to do this in `groovy`.
Kindly Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
def strings = [ 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx111',
                'xxxxxxxxxxxx111',
                'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx1111',
                'xxxxxxxxxxx223' ]
```

You could try:

```
def cutdown =  strings.collect {
    ( it =~ /(.{3}[0-9]+)/ )[ 0 ][ 1 ]
}
```

Or shorter:

```
def cutdown = strings*.find( ~/.{3}[0-9]+/ )
```

Comment: Is the grouping necessary? You could cut it down to `(it =~ /.{3}[0-9]+/)[0]` without it. Also perhaps adding an end of line depending on what the rest of the characters could possibly be `/.{3}[0-9]+$/`?

Comment: @doelleri Added an alternative with `find`, an end of string marker is probably a good idea, but it's hard to say as the question is a bit vague (as to what `x` can be for instance)

Comment: Agreed. Saw your update right as I added my comment. I like the `find` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution also worked

```
cardnumber.substring(StringUtils.countMatches(cardnumber, "X") - 3)
```